# `PySet` object recognized as `str` object

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

The following is my java code:

```
public void testPySet() {
    final PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    final String userCode = "def test(x):\n\tprint(x)\n\tx.add(\"d\")\n\treturn x";
    interpreter.exec(userCode);
    final PyObject method = interpreter.get("test");
    final PySet set = new PySet(PyString.TYPE);
    set.add("a");
    set.add("b");
    set.add("c");
    final PyObject result = method.__call__(set);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

When I run it, it will throw out an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in test
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add'
```

If I remove the `x.add(\"d\"`), then it will run successfully.

It's very weird that the `PySet` object is recognized as an `str` object.

Does anyone happen to know why?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from Jim Baker on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/jython-users):

The problem is in the line

```
final PySet set = new PySet(PyString.TYPE);
```

I think you are trying to use this as if it were PySet set = new PySet(), but actually it means that the type of the resulting object in Python code should be PyString. Which is exactly what you observe!

(Why is the case? We have two object models in Jython: Python and Java, and we have to combine support in the runtime. It can be a bit tricky to do so!)

The solution is very simple: change the initialization to

```
final PySet set = new PySet()
```